# phpmailer Return-path

Tags: phpmailer

How can I set the Return-path in phpmailer?
I have this:

```
$mail = new PHPmailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->SetFrom($_SESSION['user_mail'], $_SESSION['user_name']);

$mail->AddAddress($leverancier_mail, $leverancier_mail);
$mail->AddBCC($config['kopie_mail'], $config['kopie_mail']);

$mail->AddReplyTo($_SESSION['user_mail'], $_SESSION['user_name']);
$mail->Sender = $_SESSION['user_mail'];
```

When an mail is returned it is send to the administrator instead of the sender. How can I make it return to the sender?

Answer (score 2):

PHPMailer class sets Return-path automatically to From or Sender:

```
public function CreateHeader() {
    ...

    if(empty($this->Sender)) {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', trim($this->From));
    } else {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', trim($this->Sender));
    }

    ...
}
```